# How to drag stencil images in drawing in Calligra Flow?

Tags: drag-and-drop, calligra

How do you drag stencil symbols from the palette into the drawing with Calligra Flow 2.8?

I am just trying to drag and drop and it doesn't work. Is there some mode switching step I have missed?

Comment: How does this relate to Ubuntu?

Comment: @Mitch Is there a more appropriate stackexchange it can be moved to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the drag and drop function for Stencils.

In the meantine the Stencil palette needs to be switch to List view for dragging Stencil images into the drawing. It is expected to be fixed in Calligra Flow 2.8.1.